# Error from Mailgun API when try to create a domain

Tags: email, mailgun

When I try to create a domain from the **Mailgun API** (i.e. `POST /domains`) I receive an error :

> **"One of your domains is permanently disabled. You are not allowed to create new domains.".**

I couldn't find this error documented anywhere and I'm only guessing what it means. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At some point, I realized what the error says and found out that one of the domains in my Mailgun account has been blocked and this prevents me from creating new domains until the issue is solved.